# When does a USART 'buffer ready' bit turn on?

Tags: uart, atmel, buffer, atmega328p

I have an Atmel328P mini Xplained. The [datasheet](https://static6.arrow.com/aropdfconversion/65d19a89a4a2dbc52152b0afb98c31e87906937c/13atmega328_p20avr20mcu20with20picopower20technology20data20sheet20.pdf) specifies `UCSR0A (1 << UDRE0)` as a 'buffer ready' signal. This reads 1 if the receive or transmit buffer is available.

I'm having trouble interpreting the datasheet. Does this bit read 1 after the transmit or receive is finished (I can imagine some problems here with receiving) or does it read 1 after each frame that is processed?

Edit:
Question is general. I assume that something as basic as a buffer ready signal is shared between implementations of USART. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: At least give people a page where you referencing the datasheet. Thx

Comment: Ctrl+f > "UDRE0". Page 247.

Comment: there is no 'shared buffer' - transmit and receive are separate. it's just that they share the same register address. For the transmit you have the TXC and UDRE and for receive you have the RXC bits.

Comment: To me the description clearly states, the flag is set when the data was transmitted.

Comment: UDRE0 only reflects the state of the transmit buffer (TXB).

Comment: @schnedan I see. It appears my faulty interpretation of the buffer being shared, shorted mý circuit, haha. UDRE being transmit only, makes me understand how the controller would know when it's ready.

Comment: the datasheet sections 24.7 and 24.8 outline the operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USART Data Register Empty (UDRE) flag is only used for transmission. From the datasheet:

> The Data Register Empty (UDRE) flag indicates whether the transmit
> buffer is ready to receive new data. This bit is set when the transmit
> buffer is empty and cleared when the transmit buffer contains data to
> be transmitted that has not yet been moved into the Shift register.